# JAVA Rewrite/store only specified key value of properties

Tags: java, properties

Let say i have property file `test.properties`.

There are already defined some key/values pairs e.g:

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
key3=value3
```

I change in memory some value of these properties (let say only one key's value). I would like to store changes into property file, but to store really only changed key/value => not rewrite whole file.

Is that possible?

Any implementation of some library to I could achieve something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Look at `java.util.prefs.Preferences`

EDIT:

This is a Java utility class that does what you seem to want -- store key/value pairs (only strings as keys) without having to (re)write an entire file of them to change one value.  Java has implemented them with system-dependent backing so they're portable.

Comment: Ok, and what **specifically** must the OP pay attention to when looking at `java.util.prefs.Preferences`?

Answer (score 0):

```
    String fileName = "C:\\test\\test.txt";
    File f = new File(fileName);
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream(f);
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(is);
    p.setProperty("key3","value4");
    OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
    p.store(os,"comments");
```

But I think this will overwrite the entire properties file.

Comment: Yes, this is actually not what I meant